# How to add code into the linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, tcp, linux-kernel, kernel

I am studying how to analyse and evaluate the TCP/IP protocol stack of Linux. My goal is to study the performance of the tcp/ip protocol stack as a whole, to study the time cost of each layer and interaction between the layers of tcp/p protocol and queuinf of the ip layer.

To do the above : I am using a probing node based schema to to study the internal behaviour of TCP/IP protocol of linux. probing node is a piece of code added into the kernel to record the information like timestamp, queuing length and size of packet.

my question : how to add the probing node into the kernel ?

Comment: Avoid patching the kernel if you don't know well Linux. Otherwise, dare writing your own kernel mode. See http://kernelnewbies.org/

Comment: @user3458454 See *Kprobe* and *Jprobe*: http://www.opensourceforu.com/2011/04/kernel-debugging-using-kprobe-and-jprobe/

Comment: Is it possible send the timestamp from the kernel back ?? I dont want to store it in a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (for example) [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/), the main idea behind this tool is to put probing node somewhere: kernel or userspace program.

If you do not have time to learn SystemTap, you can just put some `printk` in the kernel and read them from `dmesg`.

In both cases, you are introducing a big delay in the network stack due to the prints. In order to reduce the delay introduced by probing, I suggest you to use SystemTap, store all your time-sample somewhere and print only at the end of acquisition.

Comment: how to get the timestamp of the kernel when it starts scheduling the newly arrived data via the tcp/ip layer ?? I am analying the interrupt latency when the data as arrived on the socket in kernel and when it start scheduling in kernel .

Comment: here an example: https://sourceware.org/systemtap/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/iotimesect.html. But you have to adjust for your case